# Trying to switch my headphone jack settings in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, realtek-hd-audio

I don't know if this is a Windows setting or not, but here goes:

I have an Acer Aspire E5-757G laptop.  Previously, when I put something into the headphone jack, it would bring up a dialog box asking what type of device it was.  It had an option "Do not ask again" and I checked it one day.  Now I need to make it ask again and I **cannot** find the setting to save my life.  Help?

Answer (score 1):

1. In the search box on the taskbar, type control panel, and then select Control Panel.
2. Hardware and Sound
3. Click audio or realtek. If you can't find go back to Control Panel, change top-right 'View by:' to Large Icons
4. Look for headphone checkbox
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Also worth noting is that in windows 10, when you press the volume button, if you have more than one audio device you will have a "drop upp" above the volume slider, if you select another device on it you will change what device is used for output.

This is a new feature in windows 10 that took me some time to figure out, but it's really convenient if you have booth speakers and headset.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is 2 years old but I had the exact same problem and it took me a while to figure out the solution. This is not a Windows issue but a Realtek one.

1. Type "Realtek" into the windows search bar and click on the "Realtek Audio Console" app.
2. Click "Device advanced settings".
3. Under "ANALOG", change from "Headphone" to "Headset".
4. Make sure the default Recording device (Control panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Manage audio devices -> Recording) is set to the Realtek Microphone.

I hope this works for anyone else.